# Javascript - How to store result of the for loop into the variable?

Tags: javascript, loops, variables

This the data that I'm trying to parse, especially "text" value from the indexes:

```
(8) [a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a]
0:a {id: 2, articleId: "1156688772", type: 2, html: "<div id="DIV_1" style="box-sizing:border-box;color…ionUI.enableUserInput()    }</script></div></div>", text: "Fyll ut feltene under for å starte en chat: Alle f…tionSession.conversationUI.enableUserInput()    }"}
1:a {id: 3, type: 5, date: 1529671597923, html: "", text: ""}
2:a {id: 4, type: 1, html: "hvordan får jeg tak i en sånn bombrikke", text: "hvordan får jeg tak i en sånn bombrikke"}
3:a {id: 5, articleId: "1140973712", type: 2, html: "Gratulerer med ny bil! Velg den avtalen som passer for deg:", persistentOptions: Array(2), …}
4:a {id: 6, type: 1, html: "er det gratis med elbil", text: "er det gratis med elbil"}
5:a {id: 7, articleId: "1158440612", type: 2, html: "<p>El-biler passerer forel&oslash;pig gratis i&nbs…g i Norge,&nbsp;hvis man har AUTOPASS-avtale.</p>", text: "El-biler passerer foreløpig gratis i de fleste bomanlegg i Norge, hvis man har AUTOPASS-avtale."}
6:a {id: 8, type: 1, html: "a med dere", text: "a med dere"}
7:a {id: 9, articleId: "1158681852", type: 2, html: "<p>Jeg beklager, jeg forst&aring;r ikke sp&oslash;…. Kan du si det p&aring; en annen m&aring;te?</p>", text: "Jeg beklager, jeg forstår ikke spørsmålet ditt. Kan du si det på en annen måte?"}
length:8
__proto__
:Array(0)
```

I am trying to figure it out a best way to store a result of a for loop into variable to pass it to some HTML field. For Example I would like result of this code, which is giving me great results:

```
var chat = nanorep.floatingWidget.$refs.core.conversationSession.entries
var chatHistory = function() {
    for (var i=2; i<chat.length; i++){
        console.log(chat[i].text + ' ');
    }
}
chatHistory();
```

to be stored in the: `var history = "result of above for loop"` variable.

I was trying with the return instead of console.log, but without much success.

Is ran out of ideas, maybe anyone more experienced than me was facing similar issues in the past, and found a way to solve it?

Thanks for any kind of reply in advance.

Comment: Since that produces several logs in a loop, how exactly would you like it to return? Probably: as an *array* of values?

Comment: You can store it in an array, or object, but it depends on your needs, we need more info

Comment: @deceze, Darmian Peralta I would have to try both ways, but as a object is preferred. Because i have to pass it to HTML element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could map the values from index 2 and onwards and join each text. Or take the array without joining for later processing.

```
var chat = nanorep.floatingWidget.$refs.core.conversationSession.entries,
    chatHistory = function() {
        return chat.slice(2).map(({ text }) => text).join(' ');
    };

console.log(chatHistory());
```

Comment: then instead of `console.log(chatHistory());` i would like to try something like:
  `chatHistory2 = chatHistory();
  chatHistory3 = chatHistory.replace(/\./g, "\n")`

Comment: you can do what you need and works with the result. does it actually work for you?

Comment: It gives me the result perfectly, but instead of passing it to console.log i have to find a way somehow to collect the result of your code to a new variable. That's because I have option only to pass the information as a variable name. like for example:

`customField: chatHistory`

Any ideas on that ?

Comment: Provide example data in your post.

Comment: @NinaScholz also this is becoming more similar to my previous question, but that wasn't my intention, I was trying to do something different, but anyway you come with the solution again, so Thank You once more, and also thanks to anyone who porvided ideas. I learned something new today, with no intention to do it :)